# Continue button not working in magento

Tags: magento, button, continue

At Checkout page, when I click on continue button, it is not working.

[image]

When I press continue button, In console this error messages display.

[image]

**Note:** I concern with already submitted questions on Stackoverflow.

But not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me after an update. The continue button worked in the desktop view but not in the iphone theme

Solution: I replaced the file
/app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

with a correct file (I took it from an old installation)

Answer (score 0):

well, is not about the file but permissions, check that every folder has a 755 and files 644
try ssh

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod +x mage

or if you are using cpanel, best to use filezilla to change it recursively

good luck
ivan Rojas
loom5.com